# Call backend .NET dll from ASP.NET Web api

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I building client server app.

The business logic is build in C++ /CLI.
In the same solution I have ASP.NET Web api project.

For logon i have method in backend. For logon i need to do this

```
using Back_End;
public IHttpActionResult Logon([FromBody]Logon_Request model)
{
 string Answer = Back_End.Logon(model.Name, model.Password);
}
```

Back_End is inside of the dll in the same solution.

When I try to call api/logon it retunes me an exception.

```
{
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "Could not load file or assembly 'Back_End, Version=1.0.5676.23091, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Attempt to load an unverifiable executable with fixups (IAT with more than 2 sections or a TLS section.) (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131019)",
"ExceptionType": "System.IO.FileLoadException",
"StackTrace": ".........."
}
```

Of course, because it is not on IIS server.

Finally my questions:

-But do I need to deploy all my business logic dll on server?

-Will whey work here?

-Is any "better" way to do what I want?

-Maybe I need to sun it as a service and make calls? But it will be API for API.

Comment: Add the assembly/ .dll to your web config file and your markup code for the Login.aspx or whatever file you're including your logon in.

Comment: Thank you. Can you be more specific, please? Where, what and how. I am new in web api. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Web.Config File**

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="yourTargetFramework">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="yourAssemblyName, Version=yourAssemblyVersion, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=yourPublicKeyToken" />
      </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

**login.aspx page**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="yourAssemblyName, Version=yourAssemblyVersion, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=yourPublicKeyToken" Namespace=".dll Namespace" TagPrefix="name to call the loginUserControl" %>
```

Ex.

`...TagPrefix="rs" %>`

`<rs:Login/>`

Comment: The exception sounds like the problem has nothing to do with ASPX pages.

Comment: I had the same error registering my `.dll`'s with bad references. Once I either added references and removed my registers or removed the references from the project and left them in the `bin` folder and registered them on the web pages, this error went away.

Comment: @usr I believe that the .dll I had a bad reference with was an attempt to reload a `.dll` with some potentially unmanaged code. Think that would be the issue here? Although I'm not seeing where unmanaged code would mix in with managed code in his scenario,.

Comment: Thank you. I can check it Monday. But I not feel what it will be the solution in my case. Probably I will need to build service.